# Major Performance Difference for RMySQL::dbWriteTable between R / Windows 10 and R-Studio / Debian GNU Linux 9

Tags: r, linux, windows, debian, rmysql

Using `RMySQL` I am trying to insert a large number of rows into an AWS MySQL InnoDB. I am experimenting with a docker image of R-Studio on Debian GNU / Linux 9 (stretch) and R on Windows 10 OS (no VM). The R-Studio Debian Docker image is based on `rocker/verse:3.6.1`.

Using R on Windows 10, writing 1,000,000 rows is no issue. However, trying the same in R-Studio on Debian GNU I fail to write 5,000 rows (error: "could not run statement: Lost connection to MySQL server during query"). For 1,000 and 2,000 rows, however, the execution time seems similar.

In both cases, I am using R version 3.6.1 and `RMySQL` version 0.10.17.

R script on Debian GNU and R-Studio (instance of Docker image), trying 5,000 rows produces error: "could not run statement: Lost connection to MySQL server during query".

```
    > library(data.table)
    data.table 1.12.6 using 1 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
    > setDTthreads(threads=2)
    > library(RMySQL)
    Loading required package: DBI
    > 
    > # Test data with 1,000,000 rows
    > tbl <- data.table(tick=rep("Dummy1",1000000),tick2=rep("Dummy2",1000000),cor=rnorm(1000000))
    > 
    > # Connect to AWS RDS
    > mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='password', dbname='dbname', host='myhost')
    >
    > # 1,000 rows
    > dbWriteTable(mydb, name='cloudscript_test', value=tbl[1:1000,], row.names=F, append=T)
    [1] TRUE
    > Sys.time() - start_time
    Time difference of 0.2941678 secs
    > 
    > # 2,000 rows
    > start_time <- Sys.time()
    > dbWriteTable(mydb, name='cloudscript_test', value=tbl[1:2000,], row.names=F, append=T)
    [1] TRUE
    > Sys.time() - start_time
    Time difference of 0.3221502 secs
    > 
    > # 5,000 rows
    > start_time <- Sys.time()
    > dbWriteTable(mydb, name='cloudscript_test', value=tbl[1:5000,], row.names=F, append=T)
    Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
      could not run statement: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
    > Sys.time() - start_time
    Time difference of 1.095466 mins
    > dbDisconnect(mydb)
    [1] TRUE
```

R script on Windows 10 (1,000,000 rows works without issues):

```
    > library(data.table)
    data.table 1.12.6 using 2 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com
    > library(RMySQL)
    Loading required package: DBI
    > 
    > # Test data with 1,000,000 rows
    > tbl <- data.table(tick=rep("Dummy1",1000000),tick2=rep("Dummy2",1000000),cor=rnorm(1000000))
    > 
    > # Connect to AWS RDS
    > mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='user', password='password', dbname='dbname', host='myhost')
    >
    > ## Insert 'tbl' into MySQL InnoDB 
    > # 1,000 rows
    > start_time <- Sys.time()
    > dbWriteTable(mydb, name='cloudscript_test', value=tbl[1:1000,], row.names=F, append=T)
    [1] TRUE
    > Sys.time() - start_time
    Time difference of 0.3517108 secs
    > 
    > # 2,000 rows
    > start_time <- Sys.time()
    > dbWriteTable(mydb, name='cloudscript_test', value=tbl[1:2000,], row.names=F, append=T)
    [1] TRUE
    > Sys.time() - start_time
    Time difference of 0.29813 secs
    > 
    > # 5,000 rows
    > start_time <- Sys.time()
    > dbWriteTable(mydb, name='cloudscript_test', value=tbl[1:5000,], row.names=F, append=T)
    [1] TRUE
    > Sys.time() - start_time
    Time difference of 0.3778641 secs
    > 
    > # 1,000,000 rows
    > start_time <- Sys.time()
    > dbWriteTable(mydb, name='cloudscript_test', value=tbl, row.names=F, append=T)
    [1] TRUE
    > Sys.time() - start_time
    Time difference of 37.09445 secs
    > 
    > dbDisconnect(mydb)
    [1] TRUE
```

Any ideas to improve the R Debian/Linux performance?

Some additional info:

R Windows 10:

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

    Matrix products: default

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
    [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] RMySQL_0.10.17    DBI_1.0.0         data.table_1.12.6

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.6.1 startup_0.14.0
```

R-Studio Linux:

```
> sessionInfo()
    R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
    Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
    Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

    Matrix products: default
    BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/libopenblasp-r0.2.19.so

    locale:
     [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
     [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
     [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C             
     [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
     [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
    [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
    [6] methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] RMySQL_0.10.17    DBI_1.0.0         data.table_1.12.6
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.6.1 tools_3.6.1
```

Both are connecting to MySQL server 5.6.39-log via TCP/IP.

Any help is highly appreciated.